# Сохранение в файл записи из таблицы в качестве скрипта

Tags: mysql

Я могу сохранить запись из таблицы с помощью запроса:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'D://result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM `my_table`
  WHERE `id` = 302294;
```

но тогда у меня в файл сохранятся только значения, например:

> 302294,"2016-11-09 16:23:01",1478697787000,1...

Можно ли сохранить данные в файл таким образом, чтобы они были в виде скрипта, например:

> INSERT INTO `my_table` (`id`, `date`, `time`, `status`...) VALUES
>   (302294,"2016-11-09 16:23:01",1478697787000,1...)

Т.е. чтобы одна запись сохранялась в том же виде, в котором сохраняется дамп всей таблицы. Существует ли способ это сделать автоматически?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, что-то вроде

```
mysqldump -c "-wid=302294" yourdbname my_table
```

сделает то что нужно.